# What's the fastest way to solve these equations with powers in a field?

Tags: algorithms, finite-fields

This is for an algorithm I'm working on.  Perhaps we can work together!

We can consider the integers modulo a prime $p$.  They form a field with arithmetic operations modulo $p$.  I'd like to find the variables that satisfy the $n$ equations ($n < p$) of the form:

$\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{c_k(z_k)^m}\right)\equiv v + m w \bmod{p}$

for each $m$ such that $0\le m < n$.  Here $c_k$, $z_k$, $v$, $m$ and $w$ are all integers, but $v$, $w$ and $m$ must be nonzero.  Only $n$ is given; we're free to assign variables as we like, with $v$, $w$, and $m$ the slight exceptions.  Hopefully this simplifies the problem.

What's the quickest way to solve this problem?

**AN EASIER VARIATION**

I'd be happy for a quick solution to this easier variation instead.
The problem is to find solutions to the modified equation where the sum is taken for $N$ $c_k$s and $z_k$s where $N > n-1$:

$\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{N}{c_k(z_k)^m}\right)\equiv v + m w \bmod{p}$

In this variation, there are more variables for the same equivalence, and so it is (much) less constrained.

Any help or suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. If we can choose everything except $n$ freely, why can't we just choose $c_k=v=w=0$?

Comment: Oops, sorry - that's the trivial case.  I'll edit the question...

Comment: According to my calculations, the total number of satisfying assignments is 1,725 for $n=2, p=5$ and 7,273 for $n=2, p=7$ and 55,341 for $n=2,p=11$. The amount of satisfying assignments should grow exponentially with $n$.

Comment: I thought I saw a linear algebra method to solving equations like these, outside of modular arithmetic.  A similar method would have columns for each $c_k v_j$ over the "domain" of $k$ and $j$, which I tried, but I can't quite get the variables to work in this solution.  It would give plenty of freedom in the form of parameters, but I still don't know how to deal with the powers.

Comment: Do you mean this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: That's similar to what I was thinking of.  I think I'm making progress by using columns for only the $c_k$'s and for the righthand side.  Here I've really expanded the righthand side of the equivalence; I have a column for $v\cdot p$, $v$, then $v_1\cdot p$, $v_1$, $v_2\cdot p$, $v_2$,...  The $v_i$'s are really there to seperate each equation and to make sure that they can easily be worked modulo $p$.  This seems to be working well...